# Spring AOP - proxying object returned from method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

In this example:

```
public class ConnectionPool {
  public java.sql.Connection getConnection() {
      ...
  }
}

@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
public ConnectionPool connectionPool(...) throws Exception {
    return new ConnectionPoolImpl(...);
}
```

I want to monitor calls to java.sql.Connection.close() on Connection objects returned from getConnection().

I tried adding `@Lookup` to the getConnection() method but it had no effect.

How do I get Spring to proxy the java.sql.Connection object?

Comment: Monitor and do what?

Comment: Monitor as in add a pointcut to it. I'm writing a leak detector that will check that all connections were returned to the pool after each HTTP request.

Comment: This isn't something Spring can do alone, assuming `getConnection` returns a `Connection` object managed by your code. You'll need to intercept the `getConnection` with an `@AfterReturning` or `@Around` advice. Then you'll need to implement that advice to wrap the `Connection` object returned in some delegating object (or build a proxy), intercepting only  its `close` method, and doing your detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create proxy for the ConnectionPool and return the proxy in the bean creation method

```
@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
public ConnectionPool connectionPool(...) throws Exception {
    ConnectionPoolImpl delegate = new ConnectionPoolImpl(...);
    ConnectionPoolCallHandler callHandler = new ConnectionPoolCallHandler(delegate);
    ConnectionPool proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                ConnectionPool.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                new Class[]{ConnectionPool.class},
                callHandler);

//    return new ConnectionPoolImpl(...);
    return proxy;
}
```

and

```
public class ConnectionPoolCallHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private ConnectionPoolImpl delegate;
    public ConnectionPoolCallHandler(ConnectionPoolImpl delegate) {
        this.delegate=delegate;
    }
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
         //all invoked methods should call 
         //appropriate methods of delegate passing all parameters
         //plus your additional tracking logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Pointcut("within(java.sql.Connection.close(..)")
public void closeAspect() {}

@Around("closeAspect()")
public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
{
  joinPoint.getThis();//Will return the object on which it(close function) is called 
  //Do whatever you want to do here
   joinPoint.proceed();   
  //Do whatever you want to do here
}
```

Comment: You're making an assumption that the `Connection` objects are managed by Spring (and can therefore be proxied). Can you make that more clear and explain why you've made that assumption?

Comment: Ya you are right, This piece of code wouldn't work if connection object is not managed by spring. But considering the fact that nowhere in the question it is mentioned explicitly that it is not a spring managed bean and also looking at the tags used for this question, I believe that's a fare assumption to make.